# Stop all ec2 instances that does not contains a tag with a specific value in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I need to write a script in python for AWS lambda function to stop all ec2 instances which doesn't have particular tag or particular value for that tag.

I am using boto3 with python to get the all instances and using filter to filter all instances with that particular tag or it's tag value , but not able to get the instances which are running without that particular tag or it's value .

```python
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters = [{
         'Name': 'tag:state:scheduleName',
         'Values': ['24x7']
       }]

    #get all instances   
    AllInstances=[instance.id for instance in ec2.instances.all()]
    # get instances with that tag and value
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    RunningInstancesWithTag = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    RunningInstancesWithoutTag= [x for x in AllInstances if x not in  RunningInstancesWithTag]

    if len(RunningInstancesWithoutTag) > 0:
            print("found instances with out tag")
            ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds = RunningInstancesWithoutTag).stop() #for stopping an ec2 instance
            print("instance stopped")
    else:
        print("let it be run as tag value is 24*7")
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us your code. Rather than using a **filter**, simply retrieve a list of _ALL_ instances, then check the tags within your Python code. See also: [Start and Stop Instances at Scheduled Intervals Using Lambda and CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John suggested in comments, you are overcomplicating this using a filter.

You want something like this:

```py
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    running_with = []
    running_without = []

    for instance in ec2.instances.all():

        if instance.state['Name'] != 'running':
            continue

        has_tag = False
        for tag in instance.tags:
            if tag['Key'] == 'scheduleName' and tag['Value'] == '24x7':
                has_tag = True
                break

        if has_tag:
            running_with.append(instance.id)
        else:
            running_without.append(instance.id)

    print("With: %s" % running_with)
    print("Without: %s" % running_without)
```

Key points:

- Don't use filter and just make a single call to ec2.instances.all().
- Loop through the instances and then through tags and count with and without.

Comment: Did this answer your question @rahularyansharma?

Answer (score 0):

The above code works in a single account, but does not look at subaccounts. This loops through to stop all instances in all sub-organizations.

```py
import boto3

# Set the AWS Organizations client
org_client = boto3.client('organizations')

# Get all accounts in the organization
accounts = org_client.list_accounts()

# Loop through each account and stop all EC2 instances
for account in accounts['Accounts']:
    print(f"Stopping instances in account: {account['Name']} ({account['Id']})")
    
    # Get all running instances and stop them
    reservations = boto3.client('ec2').describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
    for reservation in reservations['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
            print(f"Stopping instance: {instance_id}")
            boto3.client('ec2').stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
```

To only stop instances with certain tags you can modify the Filter passed to describe_instances.